# Hardcooked eggs by steaming (not boiling)

Tags: eggs, steaming

Can anyone relate an exact, foolproof method of steaming eggs, to yield hardcooked eggs? I'd appreciate whatever clear, concise instructions are available on the process, including what **not** to do.

Comment: I've [moved some comments to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64774/discussion-on-question-by-user61150-hardcooked-eggs-by-steaming-not-boiling) - they're mostly about some clarifications to the question that seem to be completely resolved now by edits.

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37298/how-long-to-steam-eggs-for-instead-of-hard-boiling

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the fool-proof magical solution you are looking for, but I normally steam duck eggs or large hens eggs in a bamboo steamer over a pan of boiling water on medium-high heat for 15 minutes. 12 minutes would be adequate for a medium hen's egg.

These are the timings for a hard boiled egg, UK sizes, and always produce a delicious, perfectly cooked egg with a bouncy white and smooth, fudgy yolk.

Comment: I go with 13 minutes, but yeah, it was probably cooked at 12. I prefer my hard-boiled eggs a bit more "done" than the fudgy yolk stage.

Comment: Could you clarify which sizing method you use to say "medium hen's egg"? The standard size in the US is "large" which is equivalent, I believe, to the "medium" size in the UK. For reference, [see here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/3705/33128).

Answer (score 3):

Kenji Lopez is who I'd consider to be the authority on in-shell egg cookery. There's [a simple recipe](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2014/04/steamed-hard-boiled-eggs-recipe.html):

> Add 1 inch of water to a large pot. Place steamer insert inside, cover, and bring to a boil over high heat. Add eggs to steamer basket, cover, and continue cooking, 6 minutes for soft-boiled eggs or 12 minutes for hard-boiled.

as well as [an article with a lot more detail](http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/the-secrets-to-peeling-hard-boiled-eggs.html), in particular about how he arrived at that recipe.

Comment: Would you mind editing the basic technique in here? It doesn't seem to be that complicated.

Comment: I think you mean to link to the article, not the recipe: http://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/the-secrets-to-peeling-hard-boiled-eggs.html ... Also, what Jefromi said... you need to include the main points of the article here in case the link dies at some point in the future. :)

Comment: @Catija Good article, but I posted the link I intended to post. The specific question "Can anyone relate an exact, foolproof method of steaming eggs, to yield hardcooked eggs?" is better answered by the technique/recipe page than the article explaining it. If they asked a more general question, such as how to improve their hard cooked eggs, I think the article would be more appropriate.